# Why doesn't GLOPP mutate humans?

Tags: video-games, duke-nukem

In *Duke Nukem: Manhattan Project*, it can be seen that G.L.O.P.P. (Gluon Liquid Omega-Phased Plasma) mutates alligators, rats, pigs etc. into giant monsters. But, when I (Duke) am attacked with green-colored GLOPP by some monsters, only my health point is affected and I don't see any sign of mutation. Why? Duke doesn't wear any kind of armor to protect his DNA from exposure.

Comment: Speculation: It's designed to mutate animals into a humanoid form. Since humans are already in humanoid form the agent cannot do its job on the victim's DNA and is therefore only toxic (since it tries (but fails) to rewrite the already humanoid DNA). Alternatively, Duke's vast amounts of cancer created by chain-smoking cigars protects him (and only him) from further mutation.

Comment: Maybe Duke has an STD that kills it?

Comment: @Himarm Circular closure warning.

Comment: @Skooba i voted to close this first, and now i have a reopen on the other

Comment: @Himarm Yup, Saw it. hammer needs to swing the other way

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I asked the co-creator of Duke Nukem; George Broussard this question on [twitter](https://mobile.twitter.com/georgeb3dr/status/527236519665618944).

His response is simply that Duke is too badass to mutate.

> Q : "I'm struggling to work out why Duke isn't mutated by his own GLOPP gun. Any ideas?"
>
> A : **"You can't mutate [a] bad motherf*cker.**

Comment: Haha.. Where did you ask?

Comment: @sachinshekar - Twitter link added.